# Garbage values coming on pulling data from wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created Feed section in my site in which i am pulling data from a worpress blog , the issue i am facing is that when i access the data then at some point it shows garbage values such as `Â Â , â€“` . Kindly let me know how can i modify my following code so it'll get the data as it is from the blog.

As an example:

Right (On *blog*): Peace of mind during holiday travels `–` especially for seniors in your lives

Wrong (On *feed*):Peace of mind during holiday travels `â€“` especially for seniors in your lives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following line of code fixed the garbage values issue for me :

```
$ret = $feed;     
echo htmlspecialchars_decode(htmlentities($ret, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_IGNORE, 'UTF-8'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a difference in encoding between the feed and you. You could try converting it to UTF-8 using the following:

`$utf8_content = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-8', mb_detect_encoding($content));`

Also double check your browser is set to UTF-8 as well.

Comment: Thanks, I used this to reolve my issue `htmlentities($entry->title, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_IGNORE, 'UTF-8')` just one problem this code is messing up the url else it'll handle the garbage values, kindly let me know how can i ignore the url for the code mentioned above

Comment: Using `htmlentities()` on a url probably isn't a good idea, try `urlencode()` [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)